# How to break long unordered list that is in loop into two containers next to each other

Tags: php, wordpress, list, foreach

I am using WordPress to insert `get_post_meta()` into a list. The list can be very long, and when it has reached a certain count it must break and the list must go on next to it, eg if I set it to break after 3 items it must do the following:

```
 1. List item 4. List item
 2. List item 5. List item
 3. List item 6. List item
```

Here is my code so far (I shortened it to be just 6 items, the one I have is 15 items and I want it to start next to it when 8 items have been listed):

```
<?php $amenity = get_post_meta($room->ID, "amenity", false); ?>

<ul class="list-group" style="list-style:none;">

<?php 

    foreach ( $amenity as $am ) {
        if (stripos($am, 'wifi') !== false) {
            echo '<li>' . '<i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>'. ' ' . $am . '</li>';
        } 
        elseif (stripos($am, 'fan') !== false) {
            echo '<li>' . '<i class="fab fa-pagelines"></i>'. ' ' . $am . '</li>';
        }
        elseif (stripos($am, 'coffee') !== false) {
            echo '<li>' . '<i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>'. ' ' . $am . '</li>';
        }
        elseif (stripos($am, 'fireplace') !== false) {
            echo '<li>' . '<i class="fas fa-fire"></i>'. ' ' . $am . '</li>';
        }
        elseif (stripos($am, 'umbrella') !== false) {
            echo '<li>' . '<i class="fas fa-umbrella"></i>'. ' ' . $am . '</li>';
        }
        elseif (stripos($am, 'tv') !== false) {
            echo '<li>' . '<i class="fas fa-tv"></i>'. ' ' . $am . '</li>';
        }

    }

?>


</ul>
```

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in code you can do this with some simple CSS:

```
.list-group {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3tugd1h9/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens. I don't know if it is the PHP code and the `foreach() `preventing this

Comment: you could also try `float:left;width:50%;` on your `li`s